# Sound Card not detected

Tags: windows-xp, sound-card

My brother just gave me his old PC, but he reconfigured it to Windows XP (earlier it was Windows 7) Now its saying there is no sound card. I was trying to play Grand Theft Auto IV and it said it required a sound card, which is already installed. I'm thinking the Sound card is too new for XP to read, but I've no idea what to do. Somebody please help me. (motherboard is "asus P5Q" by the way.)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the driver for the sound card is not installed. To verify this:

Click Start -> (right click) My Computer -> Properties -> Device Manager

If you see a yellow exclamation mark, then there is likely a missing driver.

[image]

If the sound card is a pci card (physically sticks out of the motherboard), find the model and download the drivers

If the sound card is built into the motherboard, find the motherboard model and download the sound drivers from the manufactures website.

While you're at it, you should also download the chipset and video card drivers because it is likely your brother missed them.